# Increase replication factor factor of tipics

Tags: json, shell, apache-kafka, jq

We have about 1k topics on a live kafka cluster. At the moment we have 6 brokers (Id's 1,2,3,4,5,6) on 3 Data Centers. Our default replication factor at cluster level is set to 3.
Now due to some unavoidable situation, we are loosing one DC(broker id 1 and2). So we have done the partition reassignment where we have reassigned partitions to brokers 3,4,5 and 6.
In addition to this for higher fault toleration we want to increase  the replication factor to 4 for all the existing topics

Below is a small sample of generated topic partitions.
Now the plan here is to keep the existing partition reassignment and just add the missing broker for e.g.

my_topic_1 p0 replicas are [4, 5, 3], and I would like this to be updated to [4, 5, 3, 6]

my_topic_2 p0 replicas are [3, 6, 4], and I would like this to be updated to [3, 6, 4, 5]

my_topic_2 p0 replicas are [6, 4, 5], and I would like this to be updated to [6, 4, 5, 3]

Sample JSON below.
I have been trying with combination of grep, sed and jq, so that we can just get the replica list for each partition, e.g.

my_topic_1 p0 replica list is [4, 5, 3] and compare it with a master list (existing brokers in cluster); [3, 4, 5, 6] and append the missing broker to the partition list,
So broker 6 is missing from the partition list; hence add 6 so partition list for topic becomes [4, 5, 3, 6]

Appreciate some suggestions

```
{
    "version": 1,
    "partitions": [{
        "topic": "my_topic_1",
        "partition": 0,
        "replicas": [4, 5, 3],
        "log_dirs": ["any", "any", "any"]
    }, {
        "topic": "my_topic_2",
        "partition": 0,
        "replicas": [3, 6, 4],
        "log_dirs": ["any", "any", "any"]
    }, {
        "topic": "my_topic_2",
        "partition": 1,
        "replicas": [6, 4, 5],
        "log_dirs": ["any", "any", "any"]
    }, {
        "topic": "my_topic_2",
        "partition": 2,
        "replicas": [4, 5, 3],
        "log_dirs": ["any", "any", "any"]
    }, {
        "topic": "my_topic_2",
        "partition": 3,
        "replicas": [5, 3, 6],
        "log_dirs": ["any", "any", "any"]
    }, {
        "topic": "my_topic_2",
        "partition": 4,
        "replicas": [3, 5, 6],
        "log_dirs": ["any", "any", "any"]
    }, {
        "topic": "my_topic_2",
        "partition": 5,
        "replicas": [6, 3, 4],
        "log_dirs": ["any", "any", "any"]
    }, {
        "topic": "my_topic_3",
        "partition": 0,
        "replicas": [4, 6, 5],
        "log_dirs": ["any", "any", "any"]
    }, {
        "topic": "my_topic_3",
        "partition": 1,
        "replicas": [5, 4, 3],
        "log_dirs": ["any", "any", "any"]
    }, {
        "topic": "my_topic_3",
        "partition": 2,
        "replicas": [3, 5, 6],
        "log_dirs": ["any", "any", "any"]
    }, {
        "topic": "my_topic_3",
        "partition": 3,
        "replicas": [6, 3, 4],
        "log_dirs": ["any", "any", "any"]
    }, {
        "topic": "my_topic_3",
        "partition": 4,
        "replicas": [4, 6, 5],
        "log_dirs": ["any", "any", "any"]
    }, {
        "topic": "my_topic_3",
        "partition": 5,
        "replicas": [5, 4, 3],
        "log_dirs": ["any", "any", "any"]
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what all of this means, but to add the missing item of `[3,4,5,6]` to a given array, just add one that values `18` (which is `3+4+5+6`) minus the current sum (`add`) of the array:

```bash
jq '.partitions[].replicas |= . + [18-add]' file.json
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/P0sKFQ37SlJ)

To make it more generic, you can provide the full array as parameter using `--argjson`:

```bash
jq --argjson full '[3,4,5,6]' '
  .partitions[].replicas |= . + [($full | add) - add]
' file.json
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/4pAw_S-v9__D)

Or generate the full list from the arrays at hand by making an array of `unique` values:

```
jq '
  ([.partitions[].replicas[]] | unique | add) as $sum
  | .partitions[].replicas |= . + [$sum - add]
' file.json
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/1-o-t30ynd-)

Comment: This is great, thanks @pmf
Is there any quick command where i change "log_dirs": ["any", "any", "any"] TO "log_dirs": ["any", "any", "any", "any"], i.e. 3 occurrences of "any" to 4 occurrences in the same command?

Comment: @maverick `.partitions[] |= (.replicas |= . + [18-add] | .log_dirs += ["any"])` or `.partitions[] |= (.replicas |= . + [18-add] | .log_dirs[3] = "any")`

Comment: yes, got it
```jq --argjson full '[3,4,5,6]' '.partitions[].replicas |= . + [($full | add) - add] |.partitions[].log_dirs += ["any"]' file.sjon```

Comment: So, say the master array is [3,4,5,6] and the target array is of just two elements [3, 4]; how would the jq command alter to cater to this scenario? I,e add missing elements from the master array to target array

Comment: @maverick You can also subtract whole arrays from each other which gives a list of all missing items, then add that as usual: `.replicas += ([3,4,5,6] - .replicas)`.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't get it ```jq '.partitions[].replicas += ([1,2,3,4,5,6] - .replicas) |.partitions[].log_dirs += ["any"]' file.json```
```jq: error (at file.json:1): array ([1,2,3,4,5,6]) and null (null) cannot be subtracted```

Comment: @maverick My response was based on the context from my first comment starting with `.partitions[] |= `. In full: `.partitions[] |= (.replicas += ([3,4,5,6] - .replicas) | .log_dirs += ["any"])`.

Comment: I think i got it now:
```jq '.partitions[].replicas += ([1,2,3,4,5,6] - .partitions[].replicas) | .partitions[].log_dirs += ["any"]' file.json```

Comment: a folloup from the previous comment, say the master list array changes to [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], is there any mechanism to increase the existing replica array from 3 to 4 , and the 4th element to be added is picked up from the existing master array  list in a round-robin fasion?